# Auto Flip Tab on specific time duration

Tags: javascript, jquery

All

I am using this flip tab for my project.

This is js fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/ajaypatel_aj/XbhUW/1/

Js code

```
$('document').ready(function(){
$('#flip-container').quickFlip();

$('#flip-navigation li a').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $('#flip-navigation li').each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        });
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
        var flipid=$(this).attr('id').substr(4);
        $('#flip-container').quickFlipper('', flipid, 1);

        return false;
    });
});
```

});​

I tried the below code:

```
   $('document').ready(function(){
        $('#flip-container').quickFlip();

        $('#flip-navigation li a').each(function(){
            $(this).delay(800)(function(){
                $('#flip-navigation li').each(function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('selected');
                });
                $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
                var flipid=$(this).attr('id').substr(4);
                $('#flip-container').quickFlipper('', flipid, 1);

                return false;
            });
        });
    });​
```

But it didn't work for me.
What i want is auto flip this for 1000 ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#flip-container').quickFlip();

    $('#flip-navigation li a').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $('#flip-navigation li').each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
            });
            $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
            var flipid=$(this).attr('id').substr(4);
            $('#flip-container').quickFlipper('', flipid, 1);

            return false;
        });
    });

    var id = 0;
    function autoFlip(){
        $('#flip-navigation li a:eq('+id+')').click();
        id++;
        if (id > 2) id=0;
    }
    setInterval(autoFlip, 1000);
});
```